# android:requiresSmallestWidthDp not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

This is my manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="310" />
```

I have two layout folders:**layout-sw310dp, layout-sw532dp**

**"However, Google Play currently does not support this attribute for filtering (on Android 3.2), so you should continue using the other size attributes if your application does not support small screens."**

Whats up with this? So How am I supposed to exclude those devices with SmallestWidthDp lower than 310?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in devices older than 3.2 is

```
<support-screens 
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Although small screen size is at least `426dp x 320dp`, I wouldn't worry too much about it because a medium screen size is usually about `480dp x 320dp`. I'd say setting `android:smallScreens="false"` should exclude all devices with width smaller than 310dp while at the same time wouldn't exclude medium screen devices with 320dp wide.